# How do I append text to many user inputs within the same html class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have an html form, that has many inputs within the same html class.  When the user presses the submit button, I need every input field to submit whatever the user wrote in them, and then a specific string.  If a user puts the word "cat" in the text box, the form would submit "catPTQ".  I have a function that sort of accomplishes this, but instead of retaining the user input, it just uses the first instance of a input in the class.  The function I have looks like this.

```
$(function () {
            $('#question_entry_submit_button').on('click', function () {
                var text = $('.ptq');
                text.val(text.val() + 'ptq');
            });
        });
```

This does loop through the html class of '.ptq' and append "ptq" to the end of the user input, but no matter what the user inputs into the second input box and onward, it submits the first user input + 'ptq' as in place of the actual user input + 'ptq'.

I think that makes sense, but I can try and clarify if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function) 's callback function,

```
text.val(function(_,val){
  return val + "ptq";
});
```

Full code,

```
$(function() {
   $('#question_entry_submit_button').on('click', function () {
      var text = $('.ptq');
      text.val(function(_,val){
        return val + "ptq";
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: @j Glad to help! :) And by the way try to press the tick mark present with this answer, because that may help the future visitors to think that this answer has worked for you. But this is not a compulsion. :)

Comment: I am going to,  I think because my account is new I have to wait 10 minutes to accept your answer.  I have an alarm set on my phone reminding me.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This function will get the values of all inputs with class "test". In order to process u can store the values of these elements while looping through them in an array which you can use whenever you want

```
$('.test').each(function(i, obj) {
   //test
});
```